# retrieve the host interface name used by a VirtualBox interface in "bridged mode"

Tags: virtualbox, interface

I need to retrieve  the tuntap interface name used from my the VM interfaces in "bridged adapter" mode.
I found that this information resides in the xml file of the VirtualBox VM under:

val xml=(xmlfile \ "Machine" \ "Hardware" \  "Network" \ "Adapter" \  "BridgedInterface")

Is there any way to get this info from terminal, ad example with VBoxManage?
And if not, can i rely on the xml file for most up-to date informations or is this file updated only when the VM is shut down?

Answer (score 1):

interfaces names in bridge mode is always different, starting from tap0 up to unlimited number of tap interfaces, what you can do is to use virtualbox to specifically name the interface as you want, myvmeth0 for example, that will solve what you want to do.

To name a devices you should either use your virtualization software (virt-manager for example) or directly edit XML file, more info on editing xml file at http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking

Comment: My program is a diagnostic sw that will run in an unknown environment, so I don't want  to modify config files, only to retrieve info from them. Thanks for the KVM tip, anyway!

Comment: Does it use libvirt? if it does you can do what i suggested, make sure by running virsh list, if you can see the vm that created by your software then it's libvirt based, and there is room for lots of flexibility

Comment: yes, support for it is planned in future [releases](https://sites.google.com/site/showmynetworkstate)